# has_many :through in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

Please I need help with a clear explanation of what is going on in this Rails code:

```
has_many :active_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :passive_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "followed_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
```

Why not use the underlying model name 'relationship' instead of 'active_relationship'?
What does the outcome look like?

Comment: Look at the `foreign_key:` options on those first two `has_many`s. One gives you followers, the other followees. The `has_many ... through:` associations bypass the `Relationship` join model and go straight to followers and followees (which are presumably some sort of user or person model).

Comment: @dbugger this has absolutely nothing to do with multiple inheritance. Its a join table that points to the same table twice.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly typical setup where you have two foreign key relations pointing to the same table on a model.

> Why not use the underlying model name 'relationship' instead of
> 'active_relationship'?

Because if you create two associations with the same name the later will just overwrite the former.

For example if we modified the example to:

```
has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id", dependent: :destroy
```

When we join `User.joins(:relationships)` Rails will create the query `JOINS relationships ON relationships.followed_id = users.id`. And we would have no way of getting the followers at all.

That's why you need unique names and associations.